# C# datagridview in tabPage2 affected by datagridview in tabpage1

Tags: c#, winforms, user-interface

I have a tab control named TabControl1 and have 2 TabPages in TabControl1. I had insert different DataGridView control in each TabPage. There is no problem for datagridview1 in tabPage1. However, when I click tabPage2, the data value in the first column of datagridview1 in tabPage1 will appear in the first column of datagridview2 in tabPage2. I need to click on the datagridview2 in tabPage2, then it will just get the value that is supposed to appear inside the data table. Other columns have no problem.

I have tried with

```
.refresh() / .update() 
(tabControl1.SelectedTab = tabControl1.TabPages[1].Refresh());
```

to refresh the datagridview2 in tabPage2 when i first load the GUI but there is not working.

Any hints or suggestions to solve this?

[Column in datagridview1 in tabPage1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SkK5Q.png)

[Column in datagridview2 in tabPage2 - This is what I want to get](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zclOQ.png)

[Column in datagridview2 in tabPage2 - Problem I met now](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YWrlC.png)

In datagridview2 in tabPage2, supposed it only has the first name there(second pic), but what I get currently is the first column will get affected by data in datagridview1 in tabPage1 (third pic).

The data in DataGridView is read from the XML file.

Comment: I couldnt reproduce your complaint in a net5 winforms app: https://i.stack.imgur.com/iKZkh.gif - can you post a full repro?

Comment: Maybe some event handlers remain on DGV2 from DGV1, so they fill your column in DGV2? Need code examples to analyze.

Comment: However, when i click tabPage2, the data value in the first column of datagridview1 in tabPage1 will appear...". Do you mean "**will** appear", or "**should** appear"? Do you want that as soon as you open tabPage2, that the first column of datagridview 2 is filled with the data of the first column of datagridview 1

Comment: @HaraldCoppoolse I mean "will appear", I do not want the datagridview in tabpage2 get affected by the datagridview in tabpage1...I had add some pictures on the problem that I met.

Comment: tabControl1.SelectedTab = tabControl1.TabPages1.Refresh() - this does not make any sense. One should not affect the other, your are probably using some reference incorrectly, without the actual code we won't be able to help you. You should debug and check the values step by step.